# Update file referenced by require

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file (`app.js`) which imports other JS file (`config.js`) via `require`. The imported file imports some other files and so on.

I am able to read the data of imported file in the `app.js`, but now I want to update the values in the imported file. The values in `config.js` are coming from other imported files. I tried to update the values in the following way, but it does not update them:

app.js

```
let config         = require ( 'config.js' );
config.db.user     = "newUser";
```

config.js

```
const dbConfig        = require ( './config-db' );
const assetsConfig    = require ( './config-assets' );
const smtpConfig      = require ( './config-smtp' );

module.exports = {
    db              : dbConfig.db,
    assets          : assetsConfig.assets,
    smtp            : smtpConfig.email
};
```

config-db.js

```
module.exports = {
    db : {
        user     : 'user',
        password : '******',
        server   : 'test-db.test.com',
        database : 'testDB',
        timezone : '+02:00'
    }
};
```

Is there a way I can update the values in my `config-db` from `app.js`?
Does `require` performs a two way binding?

**Update:**

After using [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Syntax) the value gets updated in the running instance of the `app.js`. The value in the file still remains the same. And once I restart `app.js` the change is lost, which is not what I want.

app.js

```
let config       = require ( 'config.js' );
config.db.update = "{'user': 'newUser'}";
```

config-db.js

```
module.exports = {
    db : {
        set update ( data ) { // jshint ignore:line
            this.user = data.user;
        },
        user     : 'user',
        password : '******',
        server   : 'test-db.test.com',
        database : 'testDB',
        timezone : '+02:00'
    }
};
```

Comment: May a set function is the way to go...

Comment: @Jonasw Are you referring to this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Yeah, but im not that experienced with nodejs, may someone who knows better will specify why uts not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
config.db.user = value
```

config.db is the reference to your config-db.js module

Comment: i've just tested this. if you change the value from app.js, and run console.log from another module, the value will be the same. but if you restart the app.js, the changes will be discarded

Comment: Yes I got that. Is there a way to preserve the value upon restart too?

Comment: Save your config file as json file, then open it as a file, not a module, and change the value, then overwrite the file. next time you run app.js there will be another values

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can update the values in my config-db from app.js?

For purposes of speed up code loading, and workaround circular `require` references, every node.js process has it's own require-cache. Of cource, you can clear it by this way - https://gist.github.com/joerx/3296d972735adc5b4ec1

But more usable way is using hot module reloading, which can be easily achieved by perform compiling server-side code into bundle by Webpack. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/
In this case you can use ES6 imports, and also don't think about re-import module - it will be replaced automatically, and re-import into target variable.